# How to clear all bpy.app.timers from previous script execution?

Tags: python, scripting, timer

How do you clear all timers in [`bpy.app.timers`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.timers.html)? It seems like there is no straightforward way, if not impossible, to clear timers that have run from previous script execution. It is easy to do for [`bpy.app.handlers`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html), you just call the `clear()` function of the handler.

```
import bpy

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.clear() # easy clear everything from previous execution as well
bpy.app.timers.clear() # but this does not exist

def some_handler(scene, depsgraph):
    print("some_handler", scene, depsgraph)

def some_timer():
    print("some_timer")
    return 2.0

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(some_handler)
bpy.app.timers.register(some_timer)
```

And of course you can't clear a previous `some_timer` function using `bpy.app.timers.unregister(some_timer)` from a previous execution because that function will have another pointer address `<function some_timer at 0x00000000XXXXXXXX>`

Current workaround is to close the file and re-open the file or open a new one. Is there any fix or any other workaround for this so I don't have to close the file?

Comment: Perhaps find a place to store that function address explicitly like `bpy.__some_timer` and retrieve it later run of the script?

Comment: @HikariTW holy cow it works! thank you so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @[HikariTW](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/73532/hikaritw) for the current workaround, which is to save the function pointer of the timer callback into an attribute appended to the `bpy` module, albeit potentially considered namespace pollution:

```
import bpy

try:
    bpy.app.timers.unregister(bpy.some_timer_function_pointer)
except:
    pass

def some_timer():
    print("some_timer")
    return 2.0

bpy.app.timers.register(some_timer)
bpy.some_timer_function_pointer = some_timer
```

Anything stored in an attribute appended to the `bpy` module, will still exist on a script re-run.

Comment: Mandatory avoid bare `try: except:`, always catch exactly the exceptions you know you'll be catching, otherwise other types of exceptions will be silenced. Here I think it's a `RuntimeError` ?

Comment: yes that is correct. actually i used `hasattr(bpy, 'some_timer_function_pointer')` at first. but decided to make it shorter just for demo purposes :)